# Dynamically link audio source elemnt into gstreamer audiomixer element

Tags: c++, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to mix internal audio and microphone audio using gstreamer audiomixer element, and then mux the single stream with video data, so far I can do it only when the soundcard is already active.
 I am using Waspisrc , waspisrc `loopback=true property`.
What I mean is my code works when there is already some song is being played in the computer and then i start my code, it works.
What i want to acheive is , internal sound src can link with audiomixer element dynamically , and it just gives me error, the program crashes , what i did so far is put the soundcard source elemnt in another bin than the main pipeline, and add a data probe in the wasapisrc element, when there is sound from audio i try to link the source with queue and then audiomixer in the main pipeline.
Any help how can i acheive dynamically link and unlink src element into audiomixer?
my code is below:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
//#include "pch.h"

#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
GMainLoop* mainLoop;
GstElement *mainPipeline;
GstPadLinkReturn link_to_mixer(GstPad* binPad, GstElement* mix);
GstPad* retrieve_ghost_pad(GstElement* bin, GstElement* elem);
typedef struct _elemStruct
{
   GstElement  *micSource, *micSourceQueue, *soundCardSrc, *soundCardSrcQueue, *micSrcRate, *micRateQueue, *soundCardRate, *soundCardRateQueue, *audioMixer, *audioMixerQueue;
   GstElement* audioConverter, *audioConverterQueue, *audioEncoder, *audioEncoderQueue, *avMuxer, *gdiGrabber, *videoConverter, *x264encoder;
   GstElement* muxerQueue, *fileSinker, *gdiGrabberQueue, *videoConverterQueue, *x264encoderQueue;
   GstCaps *caps;
   GstElement* message;
   GstStateChangeReturn stateRet;
   GstElement *micBin, *soundCardBin, *screenBin, *audioBin;
   GstPad *micMixPad, *soundCardMixPad, *audioMuxPad, *videoMuxPad;
   GstBus* mainBus;
   GstStateChangeReturn ret;
   GstMessage* msg;
   guint bus_watch_id;
   GstElement* soundCardTempSink;
}elemStruct;
BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
   switch (fdwCtrlType)
   {
       // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
   case CTRL_C_EVENT:
       printf("Ctrl-C event\n\n");
       Beep(750, 300);
       return TRUE;

       // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit. 
   case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
       Beep(600, 200);
       printf("Ctrl-Close event\n\n");
       return TRUE;

       // Pass other signals to the next handler. 
   case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
       Beep(900, 200);
       printf("Ctrl-Break event\n\n");
       return FALSE;

   case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
       Beep(1000, 200);
       printf("Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n");
       return FALSE;

   case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
       Beep(750, 500);
       printf("Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n");
       return FALSE;

   default:
       return FALSE;
   }
}
void addsoundsrc_toMainline(GstPadProbeInfo* info, GstElement* bin)
{
   // we got data , add pipeline to audiomixer 
   // add bin to audiomixer
   // get bin src pad 
   // call retrieve ghostsrc function 
   //retrieve_ghost_pad()
   GstElement* queue = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(bin), "sound_card_source_queue");
   GstPad* mixpad = retrieve_ghost_pad(bin, queue);
   //link_to_mixer(mixpad, )

}
GstPadProbeReturn soundCardProbe(GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gpointer data)
{
   //GstBuffer* buffer = gst_pad_probe_info_get_buffer(info);
   GstBuffer* buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER(info);
   elemStruct* mainElem = (elemStruct*)data;
   g_print("received data in the soundcard probe ");
   //GstElement* bin = mainElem->soundCardBin;
   //bool add = gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(mainElem->audioBin), mainElem->soundCardBin);
   //gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mainElem->soundCardBin);
   //GstElement* queue = gst_bin_get_by_name((GST_BIN(bin)), "sound_card_source_queue");
   //GstPad* mixpad = retrieve_ghost_pad(bin, mainElem->soundCardSrcQueue);
   //GstPad* mixPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainElem->soundCardSrcQueue, "sink");

   //link_to_mixer(mixPad, mainElem->audioMixer);
   //addsoundsrc_toMainline(info, bin);
   return GST_PAD_PROBE_PASS;
}
void set_queue_property(GstElement* _queue)
{
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_queue), "max-size-buffers", 1000, "max-size-time", 1000000000000, NULL);
}

GstPadLinkReturn link_to_mixer(GstPad* binPad, GstElement* mix)
{
   GstPad* mixerPad;
   gchar* binPadName, *mixerPadName;
   mixerPad = gst_element_get_compatible_pad(mix, binPad, NULL);
   //mixerPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(mix, "sink_%u");
   binPadName = gst_pad_get_name(binPad);
   mixerPadName = gst_pad_get_name(mixerPad);
   GstPadLinkReturn retVal = gst_pad_link(binPad, mixerPad);  // check if succesfull;
   g_print(" a new link is creatd with %s and %s pads\n", binPadName, mixerPadName);
   g_free(binPadName);
   g_free(mixerPadName);
   //gst_object_unref(binPad);
   gst_object_unref(mixerPad);
   //gst_element_release_request_pad(mix, mixerPad);
   return retVal;
}

GstPadLinkReturn audio_link_to_muxer(GstPad* binPad, GstElement* mix)
{
   GstPad* muxerPad;
   gchar* binPadName, *muxerPadName;
   //mixerPad = gst_element_get_compatible_pad(mix, binPad, NULL);
   muxerPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(mix, "audio_%u");
   binPadName = gst_pad_get_name(binPad);
   muxerPadName = gst_pad_get_name(muxerPad);
   GstPadLinkReturn retVal = gst_pad_link(binPad, muxerPad);  // check if succesfull;
   g_print(" a new link is creatd with %s and %s pads\n", binPadName, muxerPadName);
   g_free(binPadName);
   g_free(muxerPadName);
   //gst_object_unref(binPad);
   //gst_object_unref(mixerPad);
   gst_element_release_request_pad(mix, muxerPad);
   return retVal;
}


GstPadLinkReturn video_link_to_muxer(GstPad* binPad, GstElement* mix)
{
   GstPad* muxerPad;
   gchar* binPadName, *muxerPadName;
   //mixerPad = gst_element_get_compatible_pad(mix, binPad, NULL);
   muxerPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(mix, "video_%u");
   binPadName = gst_pad_get_name(binPad);
   muxerPadName = gst_pad_get_name(muxerPad);
   GstPadLinkReturn retVal = gst_pad_link(binPad, muxerPad);  // check if succesfull;
   g_print(" a new link is creatd with %s and %s pads\n", binPadName, muxerPadName);
   g_free(binPadName);
   g_free(muxerPadName);
   //gst_object_unref(binPad);
   //gst_object_unref(mixerPad);
   gst_element_release_request_pad(mix, muxerPad);
   return retVal;
}

GstPadLinkReturn link_to_mpeg_muxer(GstPad* binPad, GstElement* mix)
{
   GstPad* muxerPad;
   gchar* binPadName, *muxerPadName;
   muxerPad = gst_element_get_compatible_pad(mix, binPad, NULL);
   //muxerPad = gst_element_get_request_pad(mix, "sink_%d");
   binPadName = gst_pad_get_name(binPad);
   muxerPadName = gst_pad_get_name(muxerPad);
   GstPadLinkReturn retVal = gst_pad_link(binPad, muxerPad);  // check if succesfull;
   g_print(" a new link is creatd with %s and %s pads\n", binPadName, muxerPadName);
   g_free(binPadName);
   g_free(muxerPadName);
   //gst_object_unref(binPad);
   gst_object_unref(muxerPad);
   //gst_element_release_request_pad(mix, muxerPad);
   return retVal;
}
GstPad* retrieve_ghost_pad(GstElement* bin, GstElement* elem)
{
   GstPad* elemPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(elem, "src");
   GstPad* ghost = gst_ghost_pad_new("ghostsrc", elemPad);
   gst_element_add_pad(bin, ghost);
   gst_object_unref(elemPad);
   return ghost;
}


static gboolean bus_call(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
{
   GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *)data;

   switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)) {

   case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
   {
       g_print("End of stream\n");
       g_main_loop_quit(loop);
       break;

   }

   case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
       gchar  *debug;
       GError *error;

       gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug);
       g_free(debug);

       g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
       g_error_free(error);

       g_main_loop_quit(loop);
       break;
   }
   case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
   {

       GstState old_state, new_state;

       gst_message_parse_state_changed(msg, &old_state, &new_state, NULL);
       g_print("Element %s changed state from %s to %s.\n",
           GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src),
           gst_element_state_get_name(old_state),
           gst_element_state_get_name(new_state));

       //if (new_state == GST_STATE_PAUSED)
       //{
       //  gst_element_set_state(mainPipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
       //}

       break;

   }
   break;
   default:
       break;
   }

   return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //gst - launch - 1.0.exe wasapisrc loopback = true\
     // ! audiorate ! queue ! mix. wasapisrc low-latency=true \
 // ! audiorate ! queue ! mix. audiomixer name=mix ! queue ! audioconvert \
 // ! queue ! avenc_aac ! queue ! muxer. gdiscreencapsrc ! videoconvert \
 // ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux name = muxer !queue ! filesink location=muxin.mp4 sync=false

   elemStruct* mainStruct = new elemStruct();;
   if (!gst_init_check(&argc, &argv, NULL))
   {
       g_printerr("couldn't initialize gstreamer\n");
       return -1;
   }
   mainLoop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

   if ((mainPipeline = gst_pipeline_new("main_pipeline")) == NULL)
   {

   }
   mainStruct->micSource = gst_element_factory_make("wasapisrc", "mic_source");
   mainStruct->soundCardSrc = gst_element_factory_make("wasapisrc", "sound_card_source");
   mainStruct->gdiGrabber = gst_element_factory_make("dx9screencapsrc", "dx9_screen_capture_source");


   mainStruct->micSourceQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "mic_source_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "sound_card_source_queue");

   mainStruct->micSrcRate = gst_element_factory_make("audiorate", "mic_audio_rate_elem");
   mainStruct->soundCardRate = gst_element_factory_make("audiorate", "soundCard_audiorate_elem");

   mainStruct->micRateQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "mic_audiorate_queue");
   mainStruct->soundCardRateQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "soundCard_audiorate_queue");    

   mainStruct->audioMixer = gst_element_factory_make("audiomixer", "audio_mixer_elem");

   mainStruct->audioMixerQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio_mixer_queue_elem");

   mainStruct->soundCardTempSink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "soundcard_temp_sink_elem");
   mainStruct->audioEncoder = gst_element_factory_make("avenc_aac", "audio_encoder_elem");
   mainStruct->audioEncoderQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio_encoder_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->audioConverter = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audio_convert_elem");
   mainStruct->audioConverterQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio_convert_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->gdiGrabberQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "gdi_grabber_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->gdiGrabber = gst_element_factory_make("dx9screencapsrc", "gdi_grabber_elem");
   mainStruct->videoConverterQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "videoconvert_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->x264encoderQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "x264encoder_queue_elem");
   mainStruct->videoConverter = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoconvert_elem");
   mainStruct->x264encoder = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "x264enc_elem");
   mainStruct->avMuxer = gst_element_factory_make("mpegtsmux", "mp4_muxer_elem");
   //if ((avMuxer = gst_element_factory_make("mpegtsmux", "mp4_muxer_elem")) == NULL)
   mainStruct->fileSinker = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "filesink_elem");
   // set up all the sources
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mainStruct->micSource), "do-timestamp", true, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mainStruct->soundCardSrc), "do-timestamp", true, "loopback", true, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mainStruct->gdiGrabber), "do-timestamp", true, "cursor", true, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mainStruct->x264encoder), "pass", 17, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mainStruct->fileSinker), "location", "sani_1486.mp4", "sync", false, NULL);
   // set up all the queues
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->micSourceQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->audioMixerQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->audioEncoderQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->gdiGrabberQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->videoConverterQueue);
   set_queue_property(mainStruct->x264encoderQueue);


   // add the src elements to each src bin
   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mainPipeline), mainStruct->micSource, mainStruct->micSourceQueue, NULL);
   mainStruct->soundCardBin = gst_bin_new("sound_card_bin");
   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mainStruct->soundCardBin), mainStruct->soundCardSrc, mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue, NULL);
   gst_element_link_many(mainStruct->soundCardSrc, mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue,NULL);
   GstPad* soundSourceprober = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainStruct->soundCardSrc, "src");
   gst_pad_add_probe(soundSourceprober, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, soundCardProbe, &mainStruct, NULL);
   gst_element_set_state(mainStruct->soundCardBin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

   // link elements in each source bin
   gst_element_link(mainStruct->micSource, mainStruct->micSourceQueue);
   //gst_element_link_many(mainStruct->soundCardSrc, mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue, NULL);



   // put this two bin in audiobin, we will connect audiobin to screenBin later
   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mainPipeline),mainStruct->audioMixer, mainStruct->audioMixerQueue, mainStruct->audioEncoder, mainStruct->audioEncoderQueue, NULL); 


   //GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_set_state(mainStruct->soundCardSrc, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   //GstStateChangeReturn retu = gst_element_get_state(mainStruct->soundCardSrc);



   mainStruct->micMixPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainStruct->micSourceQueue, "src");
   link_to_mixer(mainStruct->micMixPad, mainStruct->audioMixer);
   //mainStruct->soundCardMixPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainStruct->soundCardSrcQueue, "src");
   //link_to_mixer(mainStruct->soundCardMixPad, mainStruct->audioMixer);

   bool one_ = gst_element_link_many(mainStruct->audioMixer, mainStruct->audioMixerQueue, mainStruct->audioEncoder, mainStruct->audioEncoderQueue, NULL);

   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mainPipeline), mainStruct->gdiGrabber, mainStruct->gdiGrabberQueue, mainStruct->videoConverterQueue, mainStruct->videoConverter, mainStruct->x264encoder, mainStruct->x264encoderQueue, NULL);

   // so add this element , with main bin 
   gst_element_link_many(mainStruct->gdiGrabber, mainStruct->gdiGrabberQueue, mainStruct->videoConverter, mainStruct->videoConverterQueue, mainStruct->x264encoder, mainStruct->x264encoderQueue, NULL);

   //link_to_mixer(videoMuxPad, avMuxer);
    mainStruct->videoMuxPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainStruct->x264encoderQueue, "src");
    mainStruct->audioMuxPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mainStruct->audioEncoderQueue, "src");

   // add all the bin and muxer and filesink to main pipeline bin 
   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mainPipeline), mainStruct->avMuxer, mainStruct->fileSinker, NULL);

   link_to_mpeg_muxer(mainStruct->videoMuxPad, mainStruct->avMuxer);
   link_to_mpeg_muxer(mainStruct->audioMuxPad, mainStruct->avMuxer);
   gst_element_link(mainStruct->avMuxer, mainStruct->fileSinker);

   //gst_element_link(videoMuxPad, avMuxer);


   /* Start playing the pipeline */
   mainStruct->ret = gst_element_set_state(mainPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   // TODO , deal with ret

   mainStruct->mainBus = gst_element_get_bus(mainPipeline);
   mainStruct->bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(mainStruct->mainBus, bus_call, mainLoop);
   gst_object_unref(mainStruct->mainBus);
   // msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(mainBus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GstMessageType(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));
   g_main_loop_run(mainLoop);

   gst_element_set_state(mainPipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(mainPipeline));
   g_source_remove(mainStruct->bus_watch_id);
   g_main_loop_unref(mainLoop);
   //g_main_loop_quit(mainLoop);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this problem is solved :)

Comment: how did you solve it? Consider writing an answer (I might be helped with it as well)